# How to take the value before or after "am" and "pm"?

Tags: python, regex

I'm a bit of a starter in the regex aspect, my question is :

I have a lunch break at `5am` later today.

I have a lunch break at `5 am` later today.

The cases that should be taken under consideration are having a space between the number and `am` and not having a space.

In these first and 2 examples the value that i want is `5`.

**EDIT:** What i have tried and didn't work:

```
import re
value = re.findall('/([1-9]|1[012]) ?[ap]m/','I have a lunch break at 5am later today.')
print   value
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have asked a pretty clear question.

Comment: There isn't a question here, only a request for free labour... what have you tried?

Comment: Sure, edited the question.

Comment: @user9148659 you don't need to add delimiters in python regex. Just change your string to `r"([1-9]|1[012]) ?[ap]m"` instead. Also, you may use `(\d+) ?[ap]m` instead.

Comment: Thank you @ctwheels kindly add it in answers so i can accept.

Comment: @user9148659 you're very welcome! I added it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Brief

Python doesn't need regex delimiters to be specified. Your current regex string in python is `'/([1-9]|1[012]) ?[ap]m/'`. While this is not incorrect, the delimiter `/` used is actually taken literally in python: That is to say that it's actually trying to find `/` in the string such that the format matches - for example - `/1 am/` instead of `1 am`.

---

### Code

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/XujGDH)

```
import re

r = r"([1-9]|1[012]) ?[ap]m"
s = 'I have a lunch break at 5am later today.'

value = re.findall(r, s, re.I)
print value
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import re
value = re.search('((1[012]|[1-9])\s?(am|pm))','I have a lunch break at 5 pm later today.').group().replace('pm','').replace('am','')
print(value)
```

Comment: Well it doesn't work properly, the first test being the sentence you have above where it gave 5am istaed of 5 only, the other when i substitued 5am to 5pm i got only pm and then i changed 5am to 12 am and got 12.

Comment: you can replace 'pm' and 'am' in final value (edited the answer)

Answer (score 0):

A regex like this might work for you:

```
/([1-9]|1[012]) ?[ap]m/
```

Answer (score 0):

The () means extract this part, and in [] we specify the targets that we want, * Matches 0 or more occurrences of preceding expression.

```
import re    
s = re.findall('([0-9 ]*)am' , '5am 5 am 12 am 12am')
for x in s:
    print(x.strip())
```

Comment: I want them both in 1 regex and i want 0 to 12 .

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.